# IIS 7 can't run ASP.NET MVC application due to missing System.Web.Helpers

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I've set up IIS 7 on my Windows 2008 R2 server according to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/enabling-iis-7-x-on-windows-7-vista-sp1-windows-2008-windows-2008r2) and deployed my ASP.NET MVC application on it via the one-click publishing method in Visual Studio 2010, but the IIS server fails to run the application due to a configuration error:

*Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently I need to install MVC dependencies on the server. I found a recipe on [winhost forums](http://forum.winhost.com/showthread.php?t=8458), which says to add the required references to your project and configure them for web deployment. I followed these steps, and it solved my problem:

1. Add the following references to the project:

   - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
   - System.Web.Razor
   - System.Web.WebPages.Razor
   - System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
2. Set the property *Copy Local* to *True* for the following references:

   - System.Web.Helpers
   - System.Web.MVC
   - System.Web.WebPages
   - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
   - System.Web.Razor
   - System.Web.WebPages.Razor
   - System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
3. Re-deploy

**Edit:**

ITHedgeHog made me aware of a shortcut in Visual Studio 2010 for the above procedure:
Right click on the project and click *Add Deployable Dependencies*, you will then get a dialog in which you can simply pick ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: IF you're using VS2K10 you can achieve the same thing by right clicking on the project and selecting "Add deployable dependencies" the MVC dependency will be in there to select.

Comment: @ITHedgeHog I am indeed using VS2K10, and this is definitely a preferable shortcut! Would you say this is the recommended approach in general when deploying an MVC project? A colleague told me he would just install the MVC development kit on the server.

Comment: Personally, it depends on how may MVC Apps you're deploying and if you're going to keep updating MVC on all your apps. If you write one, then bin deploy it - if all your apps are going to be maintained then whack it on the server.

Comment: Useful information thank you. Be aware there is a gotcha where the deployable dependencies will include WebMatrix assemblies. These dlls then resulted in an attempt to redirect to a non-existent login page. Removing them from the bin directory resolved that issue.